# How to access "Retake" option in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, video, swift2, uiimagepickercontroller

I am a novice developer developing a project involving taking video from iPhone and uploading it to server. For taking the video i am using the `UIImagePickerController`. It is perfect for my requirement. It allows me to add `overlay views` to camera and set `videoMaximumDuration`. But as per my requirement i will add a overlay view after the user selects the `Use video` option. in that view I will once again have a button which has the functionality of `Retake` video. It may seem out of logic, but as per the project's requirement it is logical, Trust me. I have googled it and most people had preferred to use `AVSessionManager` and create a custom camera control. But creating a custom controlled camera similar to `UIImagePickerController` is really taking a toll on my deadline. Also i want to reuse only the `Retake` functionality.

Is there any way to use the `Retake` video after selecting the `Use Video` option or are there any workarounds for this scenario ?

I am using Xcode 7.3 Swift 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Apple doesn't allow users to reuse their functionality. The `Retake` functionality cannot be reused. So i had to go along with the default setup. So to achieve my requirement i just restarted the `UIImagePickerController` when i tap on my custom  `Retake` button without any animation.